# How to read message from telegram group if the bot is not in the group but user is?

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

How to read message from telegram group if the bot is not in the group but user is

Answer (score 0):

`for message in client.iter_messages(group_entity): print(message.text)`

[More about entities](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html)
[More about messages](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/client-reference.html#messages)